# How to increase actionbar/toolbar size and font size Xamarin multiplatform Android tablet?

Tags: android, xamarin, multiplatform

So I'm fairly new to Xamarin and mobile dev in general and I recently started working with an Android project that was already finished in iOS. I'm needing to increase the size of the toolbar/actionbar (not sure which it is, but it's the thing at the top of each page that allows you to go back to previous screens and has the page title in it) and also the size of the fonts for Android tablets. However I can't seem to get either to change sizes at all regardless of the device (phone or tablet). I've tried numerous things, but nothing has worked.

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> <!--DarkActionBar">-->
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>

    <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:height">80dp</item>-->

    <!--Action bar style-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
    <item name="height">80dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FFAA</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I've also tried it with and without the @style in front of Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar and TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title respectively, but still nothing. There is something really obvious that I'm doing wrong, but I'm just not sure what. Anything you can do to help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my NavigationPage code from Login:

```
var newScreen = new DeviceListPage();
newScreen.Title = " ";
var nav = new NavigationPage(newScreen);
this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(nav);
```

Here's the logout toolbar item from the DeviceListPage:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="tb" Text="Log Out" Clicked="btnLogOutClicked"> </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

And here's just a generic page push to the Main Page from DeviceListPage:

```
var newScreen = new MainPage(activeDeviceName);
newScreen.isFromDeviceList = true;
newScreen.Title = "Main Screen";
this.Navigation.PushAsync(newScreen);
```

UPDATE!: Ok, so I've figured out how to change the font size of the title text on the toolbar with the following custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomToolBar))]
namespace MyHealthVitals.Droid
{
public class CustomToolBar : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer
{

    private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
    {
        base.OnViewAdded(child);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("child type = "+child.GetType().ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("child type fullname = " + child.GetType().FullName);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("child type name = " + child.GetType().Name);
        if (child.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar))
        {
            toolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)child;
            toolbar.ChildViewAdded += Toolbar_ChildViewAdded;
        }
    }

    private void Toolbar_ChildViewAdded(object sender, ChildViewAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = e.Child.GetType();
        if (e.Child.GetType() == typeof(Android.Widget.TextView))
        {
            var textView = (Android.Widget.TextView)e.Child;
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Px, 80);
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, I still can't seem to figure out how to change the font size of my ToolbarItem controls. Since there are no ToolbarItem Renderers it makes this quite difficult.

Comment: Here's what it looks like currently [https://imgur.com/LFTPUDJ](https://imgur.com/LFTPUDJ)

Comment: Are you using `NavigationPage`? Could you please post the codes of related page?

Comment: Yes I'm using NavigationPage and I'm just trying to increase the font size of the title for that page and anything I put in the toolbar. I've included some code at the bottom of the post. Let me know if you need anything else.